# PDO bindValue an empty string in codeigniter

Tags: php, pdo, duplicates

I'm running an insert query to insert user information into the database. 
The fields to insert are username and email, and the email field is not mandatory.

The query run fine when the input includes the email, but when I entered nothing in the email, the PDO error always reports the error " ***Duplicate entry '' for key 'email'*** " .

```
 $post = $this->input->post();

 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email) VALUES (:username, :email)";

 $query = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($sql);

 $query->bindValue (':username', $post['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

 if ($email == false){
     $query->bindValue(':email', '', PDO::PARAM_STR );
 } else {
     $query->bindValue(':email', $post['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR );
 }

 $query->execute();
```

Comment: Try inserting an empty email as `null` instead of `''`

Comment: it returns "Column 'email' cannot be null"

Comment: The problem is the column `email` is set to unique, so you can't have two instances of an email with the value `''`. Looks like the next problem is the column is also set to `NOT NULL`. Because you are not requiring email, change the column to allow null values. Then, if the user does not enter an email, set that column to null, not an empty string.

Comment: It works. Your explanation makes a lot of sense. I was scratching my head for a few hours trying to figure out what's wrong, thanks for the help.

Comment: Oops I was a few seconds late on my answer - looks like you got it working, so the code I just posted in my answer below may not be needed :) Either way glad you were able to get it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as I mentioned in the comment, you need to set the email column to allow for null values. If you are not requiring an email address, then it is better to store a non-email as null rather than an empty string - but in this case it is necessary because the column is unique.

Then, try this code:

```
$post = $this->input->post();
if (!$post['email']){
    $post['email'] = NULL;
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email) VALUES (:username, :email)";
$query = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array($post['username'], $post['email']));
```